# html select box - load image for default selected option

Tags: php, html, select

Today I faced with a problem about html select

here is the code :

```
<select id="optdon" onchange="showimage(this);" name="optdon" style="width:<?php echo $drop_width; ?>px;">
                <option value="">--Select don--</option>
                <?php foreach($for_don as $donname) { if(isset($donname['don_name']) && $donname['status'] == 1) {  ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $donname['don_id']; ?>"><?php echo $donname['don_name']?></option>
                <?php } } ?>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <div align="center">
                <?php $i = 0; foreach($for_don as $donimage) { if(isset($donimage['don_image'])) {  ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;" id="<?php echo $donimage['don_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $donimage['don_image']?>" /></div>
                <?php  $i =  $i + 1;} }?>
```

```
function showimage(ids){
    clearall();
    if(ids.value != ''){
        jQuery('#'+ids.value).show();
    }
}
```

What is the project ? I need to select first option !!!

**It is easy but when i set the first option selected it's image doesn't load in the page first load** . option's image appears on changing options.

I have these two answers for selecting first option (when thre is just one option )

suggestion 1

```
<?php $x = 0; foreach($for_don as $donname){ if(isset($donname['don_name']) && $donname['status'] == 1) {  $x = $x + 1; }} ?>
<select id="optdon" onload="showimage(this);" name="optdon" style="width:<?php echo $drop_width; ?>px;">
    <option value="">--Select don--</option>
    <?php $z = 0; $selected='selected' ?>
    <?php foreach($for_don as $donname) { if(isset($donname['don_name']) && $donname['status'] == 1) { $z = $z + 1;  ?>
        <option  <?php if($z==1 && $x == 1)echo $selected; ?>  value="<?php echo $donname['don_id']; ?>" ><?php echo $donname['don_name']?></option>
    <?php } } ?>
</select>
<br /><br />
<div align="center">
    <?php $i = 0; foreach($for_don as $donimage) { if(isset($donimage['don_image'])) {  ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;" id="<?php echo $donimage['don_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $donimage['don_image']?>" /></div>
    <?php  $i =  $i + 1;} }?>
</div>
```

suggestion 2 :

```
<?php $x = 0; foreach($for_don as $donname){ if(isset($donname['donation_name']) && $donname['status'] == 1) {  $x = $x + 1; }} ?>
<?php if($x == 1) { ?>

    ??????

<?php } else { ?>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this JavaScript:

```
var optdon = document.getElementById('optdon');
optdon.onchange.call(optdon);
```

This will trigger the `onChange` event handler, allowing the initial option to have its effect.